# Empty response from Bitstamp.net

Tags: rest, api, http

I am trying to use the private api from Bitstamp to query for my account's balance. I believe I am posting the right data as no error is returned but Bitstamp's answer is always empty

```
*   Trying 107.154.249.133...
* Connected to www.bitstamp.net (107.154.249.133) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection:         
ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* NPN, negotiated HTTP1.1
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*    subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; CN=*.bitstamp.net
*    start date: Apr  8 14:11:39 2015 GMT
*    expire date: Apr  8 15:48:13 2018 GMT
*    subjectAltName: www.bitstamp.net matched
*    issuer: C=US; ST=Arizona; L=Scottsdale; O=GoDaddy.com, Inc.;     
OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/; CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate     
Authority - G2
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /api/v2/balance HTTP/1.1
Host: www.bitstamp.net
User-Agent: Bitstamp C++ API Client
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 134
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* upload completely sent off: 134 out of 134 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, accept, cache-control
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Content-Language: en
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Date: Fri, 08 Sep 2017 17:46:41 GMT
< Location: http://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/balance/
< Server: Apache
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains
< Vary: Accept-Language
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: visid_incap_99025=wHhR5uPzT92ReB9XbeNToIHXslkAAAAAQUIPAAAAAAAbNQJEog5ZojcqdOv0dFhd; expires=Sat, 08 Sep 2018 10:32:13 GMT; path=/; Domain=.bitstamp.net
< Set-Cookie: nlbi_99025=VyBXXwUOsQHckThX8F1n9AAAAABOW3tLZ0nUHyp47yinIimv; path=/; Domain=.bitstamp.net
< Set-Cookie: incap_ses_569_99025=04PeXe3KGFAAVw//8n7lB4HXslkAAAAA09BkGnsaiskl2dkFxzhFXQ==; path=/; Domain=.bitstamp.net
< X-Iinfo: 9-15073063-15060114 PNNN RT(1504892800858 31) q(0 0 0 -1) r(2 2)     U6
< X-CDN: Incapsula
< 
* Connection #0 to host www.bitstamp.net left intact
result: 0
response: 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Bitstamp response doesn't contain result data
```

Any idea ?
Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: Which tool are you using to send the API request? In the HTTP request, where is the API key, signature, and nonce?

Comment: I am using curl in c++ to send my request. As explained by Bitstamp (https://www.bitstamp.net/api/) : all private API calls require authentication. For a successful authentication you need to provide your API key, a signature and a nonce parameter, the signature being a HMAC-SHA256 encoded message containing nonce, customer ID and API key.

Comment: Can you provide the `curl` command (you can hide sensitive information, of course)?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue but in node. Pretty sure I'm creating the signature correctly. I've POST'ed using json and formData but getting 301 with both. Would appreciate an update if op figured this out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initially I had the balance path to be `/balance`, but after changing to `/balance/` it worked and got 200 back with payload.

So instead of `http://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/balance` use `http://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/balance/`, note the trailing backslash

Comment: Indeed, that's it ! Not sure why I did not test this in the first place...